# d3 force layout repulsive charge formula

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Is there a way to alter the formula D3 uses for calculating the charge's repulsive force in a force layout?

It was previously stated that the [D3 charge force follows the inverse-square law](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929599/249538). But, I want to make the force decay even faster as the distance between nodes increases. I want to make the formula behave something more like `charge/distance^3` or `charge/distance^4` so that nodes only significantly repel each other when they're *very* close to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the source code. The relevant file is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js), in particular the `repulse` function. What's currently

```
var k = quad.charge * dn * dn;
```

you could change to

```
var k = quad.charge * dn * dn * dn;
```

Comment: It would be nice if whoever downvoted could provide a reason for doing so. What did you expect of this answer that it didn't have?