# Appending multiline text to nodes in directed graphs in d3js

Tags: d3.js, directed-graph

I am trying to create multi line text as nodes of the directed graph as :

```
    <rect height="27" width="56" rx="100" ry="100" style="fill: #ffffff;"></rect>
    <text dx="6" dy="6">
        <tspan x="0" dy="15">Donovan</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="15">3</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="15">what</tspan>
    </text>
```

as seen in: http://jsfiddle.net/nikosdim/S4eaL/1/

I currently have this:

```
// setting up parameters to be use through rest of the code
var w = 2000;
var h = 800;
var r = 30;
var linkDistance = 100;
var boxHeight = 50;
var boxWidth = 50;
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

// This is what how we should be setting gravity, theta and charge ideally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901565/charge-based-on-size-d3-force-layout
var charge = -5000;
var gravity = 0.3;
var theta = 0.01;

var dataset = {
    nodes: [
    { "name": "Adam", "id": "0" },
    { "name": "Bob", "id": "1" },
    { "name": "Carrie", "id": "2" },
    { "name": "Donovan", "id": "3" },
    { "name": "Edward", "id": "4" },
    { "name": "Felicity", "id": "5" },
    { "name": "George", "id": "6" },
    { "name": "Hannah", "id": "7" },
    { "name": "Iris", "id": "8" },
    { "name": "Jerry", "id": "9" }
    ],
    edges: [
    { "source": 0, "target": 4 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 5 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 5 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 5 },
    { "source": 5, "target": 8 },
    { "source": 5, "target": 9 },
    { "source": 6, "target": 7 },
    { "source": 7, "target": 8 },
    { "source": 8, "target": 9 }
    ]
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({ "width": w, "height": h });

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(dataset.nodes)
    .links(dataset.edges)
    .size([w, h])
    .linkDistance([linkDistance])
    .charge(charge)
    .theta(theta)
    .gravity(gravity);

var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(dataset.edges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("id", function (d, i) { return 'edge' + i; })
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("pointer-events", "none");

var nodes = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr({ "width": boxWidth })
  .attr({ "height": boxHeight })
  //.style("fill", function (d, i) { return colors(i); })
  .style("fill", 'white')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .call(force.drag);

var nodelabels = svg.selectAll(".nodelabel")
   .data(dataset.nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr({
       //"x": function (d) { return d.x; },
       //"y": function (d) { return d.y; },
       "class": "nodelabel",
       "stroke": "black"
   });

var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
    .data(dataset.edges)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr({
        //'d': function (d) { return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y; },
        'class': 'edgepath',
        'fill-opacity': 0,
        'stroke-opacity': 0,
        'fill': 'blue',
        'stroke': 'red',
        'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgepath' + i; }
    })
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
    .data(dataset.edges)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr({
        'class': 'edgelabel',
        'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgelabel' + i; },
        'dx': 80,
        'dy': 0,
        'font-size': 10,
        'fill': '#aaa'
    });

edgelabels.append('textPath')
    .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#edgepath' + i; })
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .text(function (d, i) { return 'label ' + i; });


svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({
        'id': 'arrowhead',
        'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX': 25,
        'refY': 0,
        //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
        'orient': 'auto',
        'markerWidth': 10,
        'markerHeight': 10,
        'xoverflow': 'visible'
    })
    .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
        .attr('fill', '#ccc')
        .attr('stroke', '#ccc');


force.on("tick", tick).start();

function ConstrainX(point) {
    return Math.max(r, Math.min(w - r, point));
}

function ConstrainY(point) {
    return Math.max(r, Math.min(h - r, point));
}

function tick(e) {
    // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
    var k = 60 * e.alpha;
    dataset.edges.forEach(function (d, i) {
        d.source.y -= k;
        d.target.y += k;
    });

    edges.attr({
        "x1": function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.source.x); },
        "y1": function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.source.y); },
        "x2": function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.target.x); },
        "y2": function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.target.y); }
    });

    nodes.attr({
        "x": function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.x) - boxWidth / 2; },
        "y": function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.y) - boxHeight / 2; }
    });

    // appending boxWidth/2 to make sure the labels are within the box
    nodelabels.attr("x", function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.x) - boxWidth / 2; })
              .attr("y", function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.y); });

    edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
        var path = 'M ' + ConstrainX(d.source.x) + ' ' + ConstrainY(d.source.y) + ' L ' + ConstrainX(d.target.x) + ' ' + ConstrainY(d.target.y);
        //console.log(d)
        return path;
    });

    edgelabels.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
        if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
            bbox = this.getBBox();
            rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
            ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
            return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
        }
        else {
            return 'rotate(0)';
        }
    });

    var insertLinebreaks = function (d) {
        var el = d3.select(this);
        var name = d.name;
        var id = d.id;

        el.text('');

        //for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(name);
        tspan = el.append('tspan').text(id);
        //if (i > 0)
        tspan.attr('x', 0);
        tspan.attr('dy', '15');
        tspan = el.append('tspan').text('what');
        tspan.attr('x', '0');
        tspan.attr('dy', '15');
        //}
    };

    nodelabels.each(insertLinebreaks); <== Insert new lines
}
```

But this is messing new lines in the nodes.  Once I insert the new lines the text shows up left aligned at the start of the screen.  This is not what I want.  I wanted the text to be aligned in the node as shown in the first image.

This is the output using the above code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6afc2vp8/

Answer (score 1):

```
// **********start configuration***************
var dataset = {
    "Nodes": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "Identity": "af12689c-de83-4a0d-a63d-1f548fd02e26",
            "RoleInstance": "RoleInstance",
            "LogonID": "LogonID1",
            "WeightedScore": 120,
            "AccountInstance": "AccountInstance1",
            "MinTimestampPst": "2014-11-19T17:08:46.6797242-05:00"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Identity": "a5bd36db-00e6-4492-92d7-49278f0046a7",
            "RoleInstance": "RoleInstance2",
            "LogonID": "LogonID2",
            "WeightedScore": 100,
            "AccountInstance": "AccountInstance2",
            "MinTimestampPst": "2014-11-19T17:08:46.6797242-05:00"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Identity": "a5bd36db-00e6-4492-92d7-49278f0046a7",
            "RoleInstance": "RoleInstance2",
            "LogonID": "LogonID2",
            "WeightedScore": 100,
            "AccountInstance": "AccountInstance2",
            "MinTimestampPst": "2014-11-19T17:08:46.6797242-05:00"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Identity": "a5bd36db-00e6-4492-92d7-49278f0046a7",
            "RoleInstance": "RoleInstance2",
            "LogonID": "LogonID2",
            "WeightedScore": 100,
            "AccountInstance": "AccountInstance2",
            "MinTimestampPst": "2014-11-19T17:08:46.6797242-05:00"
        }
    ],
    "Edges": [
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 1
        }, {
            "source": 3,
            "target": 2
        }
    ]
};

// select all the features from the node that you want in the output
var nodelabelslist = ["ID", "Identity", "RoleInstance", "LogonID", "WeightedScore", "AccountInstance", "MinTimestampPst"];
var nodelabelslistlength = nodelabelslist.length;
// this is the rectangle height and width
var boxHeight = nodelabelslistlength * 20;
var boxWidth = 400;

var nodelabelverticaloffset = 15;
var nodelabelhorizontaloffset = 5;
var labelStartPos = -(nodelabelslistlength/2 - 1);

// setting up d3js parameters to be use through rest of the code
var w = 2000;
var h = 800;
var r = 30;
var linkDistance = 200;
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

// This is what how we should be setting gravity, theta and charge ideally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901565/charge-based-on-size-d3-force-layout
var charge = -6000;
var gravity = 0.10;
var theta = 0.01;

// **********end configuration***************

var jsonNodes = dataset.Nodes;
var jsonEdges = dataset.Edges;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({ "width": w, "height": h });

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(jsonNodes)
    .links(jsonEdges)
    .size([w, h])
    .linkDistance([linkDistance])
    .charge(charge)
    .theta(theta)
    .gravity(gravity);

var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(jsonEdges)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("id", function (d, i) { return 'edge' + i; })
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
    .style("stroke", "#000")
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

var nodes = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(jsonNodes)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    //.style("fill", function (d, i) { return colors(i); })
    .style("fill", 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .call(force.drag);

var nodelabelsarr = [];
for (var index = 0; index < nodelabelslist.length; ++index) {
    var nodelabels = svg.selectAll(".nodelabel" + index)
        .data(jsonNodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr({
            "class": "nodelabel",
            "stroke": "black"
        })
        .text(function (d) { return nodelabelslist[index] + ": " + d[nodelabelslist[index]]; });
    nodelabelsarr[index] = nodelabels;
}

var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
    .data(jsonEdges)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr({
        'class': 'edgepath',
        'fill-opacity': 0,
        'stroke-opacity': 0,
        'fill': 'blue',
        'stroke': 'red',
        'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgepath' + i; }
    })
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
    .data(jsonEdges)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr({
        'class': 'edgelabel',
        'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgelabel' + i; },
        'dx': 80,
        'dy': 0,
        'font-size': 10,
        'fill': '#000'
    });

edgelabels.append('textPath')
    .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#edgepath' + i; })
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .text(function (d, i) { return 'label ' + i; });


svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({
        'id': 'arrowhead',
        'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX': 25,
        'refY': 0,
        //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
        'orient': 'auto',
        'markerWidth': 10,
        'markerHeight': 10,
        'xoverflow': 'visible'
    })
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000')
    .attr('stroke', '#000');


force.on("tick", tick).start();

function ConstrainX(point) {
    return Math.max(r, Math.min(w - r, point));
}

function ConstrainY(point) {
    return Math.max(r, Math.min(h - r, point));
}

function edgeArc(d) {
    var path = 'M ' + ConstrainX(d.source.x) + ' ' + ConstrainY(d.source.y) + ' L ' + ConstrainX(d.target.x) + ' ' + ConstrainY(d.target.y);
    //console.log(d)
    return path;
}

function edgelabeltransform(d) {
    if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        var rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
        var ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
        return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
    }
    else {
        return 'rotate(0)';
    }
}

function tick(e) {
    // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
    var k = 60 * e.alpha;
    jsonEdges.forEach(function (d) {
        d.source.y -= k;
        d.target.y += k;
    });

    edges.attr({
        "x1": function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.source.x); },
        "y1": function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.source.y); },
        "x2": function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.target.x); },
        "y2": function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.target.y); }
    });

    nodes.attr({
            "x": function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.x) - boxWidth / 2; },
            "y": function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.y) - boxHeight / 2; }
        })
        .attr({ "width": boxWidth })
        .attr({ "height": boxHeight });

    // appending boxWidth/2 to make sure the labels are within the box
    var startOffset = labelStartPos;
    for (var index = 0; index < nodelabelsarr.length; index++) {
        nodelabelsarr[index].attr("x", function (d) { return ConstrainX(d.x) - boxWidth / 2 + nodelabelhorizontaloffset; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return ConstrainY(d.y) + (nodelabelverticaloffset * startOffset); });
        startOffset++;
    }

    edgepaths.attr('d', edgeArc);

    edgelabels.attr('transform', edgelabeltransform);
}
```