# D3 force directed layout: bounding box

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, bounding-box, directed-graph

A very similar question has been asked here: [D3 force directed layout with bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573178/d3-force-directed-layout-with-bounding-box) ... I tried implementing the suggested solutions but without success, so I'll ask again :(

This is my code

```
// initialization stuff happening up here...
// create graph:    

    this.onStateChange = function() {

        svg.selectAll("g").remove();
        nodes = {};
        links = [];

        links = eval(this.getState().string);
        links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name : link.source});
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name : link.target});
        });

        force.nodes(d3.values(nodes)).links(links).start();

        path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links()).enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) {return "link " + d.type;})
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) {return "url(#" + d.type + ")";});

        circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 8)
            .call(force.drag);

        text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("font-size","15px")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", ".42em").text(function(d) {return d.name;});
    };

//add gravity
    function tick() {

        path.attr("d", linkArc);
        circle.attr("transform", transform);
        text.attr("transform", transform);


        circle.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(w - r, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(h - r, d.y)); });

        path.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });


    }

    function linkArc(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, 
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y, 
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        return "M" + d.source.x + "," 
            + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr
            + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
};
```

However this doesnt work - I cannot move the nodes anymore and they are stuck in the upper right corner.

Comment: you're not setting `tick()` as a handler for the force layout's `"tick"` event.

Comment: Thanks, I added that: force.nodes(d3.values(nodes)).links(links).on("tick", tick).start(); ... however the boundaries don't seem to take effect. Nodes are flying around behind the borders of the box.

Comment: (I'd like to achieve something like this http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/bounding.html )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how it goes. If anybody wants to add a bounding box to this mobile-patent-suits example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292), this might be helpful:

```
function tick() {   
    //circle.attr("transform", transform); //no need for this anymore   

    circle.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(8, Math.min(300 - 8, d.x)); })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(8, Math.min(280 - 8, d.y)); });
    text.attr("transform", transform);
    path.attr("d", linkArc);

    }
    function linkArc(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, 
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y, 
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        return "M" + d.source.x 
                + "," + d.source.y 
                + "A" + dr 
                + "," + dr
                + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x 
                + "," + d.target.y;
    }
    //function transform(d) { //don't need this anymore either
    //return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    //}
};
```