# Bounds for networks and forces with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout, bounding-box

I need to use the algorithm of forces with a network, but that network is divided into parts.

For example, the vertices of the first part can not leave the part 1. The vertices of the part 2 need to be in part 2.

If there is a connection between a vertex from part 1 and a vertex from part 2, this connection will make these two vertices be near, however, will not let their parts.

This draft image illustrates the idea: [image: example]

I need to do this for about 8 parts. Some parts are in the other, other parts are next to each other. And the network will be represented on these parts, each vertex in their respective part, however, the algorithm forces should try to pull the connected vertices themselves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573178/d3-force-directed-layout-with-bounding-box

Comment: I saw that Bounding-box example but when I saw the code I could not find where could I set it to do more than 1 bounding-box for 1 network. I have just found this almost what I need tool: http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/
But I still do not know if it is the right tool I need. All the examples that was shown have boxes and the boxes move according to the network movement. I need that the network move according to the circles and boxes with fixed position.

Comment: You just need to modify the `tick` function to selectively target nodes and apply separate forces. Here's another example that applies different forces to different nodes based on their index in the dataset: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

Comment: My initial idea was to just use this example you quoted now. To distribute the vertices in parts that would be enough. However, when I consider the strength of the edges, would vertices not pull out of the parts?  Maybe I can create a restriction on the formulas that are in the thick function. Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: The other point is that a vertex can move freely in its own part but can not go to the other parts. As I don't know the size of networks will be visualized, i think the only contraint should be the shapes (parts) and the force-by-edges.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create constraints using the "tick" function from d3.

To improve performance and avoid "locked" vertices on corners, I decided to use only circles.

For each node:

1. Make sure it is inside its region.
2. Make sure it is also not inside each of the other regions.

This ended up in lots of calculations for each node vs. each region. This is summed with the collision detection complexity. Yet, it handled networks with around a thousand nodes.

**Details here**:
Heberle, H., Carazzolle, M., Telles, G. et al. CellNetVis: a web tool for visualization of biological networks using force-directed layout constrained by cellular components. BMC Bioinformatics 18, 395 (2017). https://doi.org/10.1186/s12859-017-1787-5

**Note for potential improvement**: one of the most expensive calculations is the combo of checking over what elements a node is. For instance, if there was a native "browser's" function that giving a point x,y it returned the elements of an SVG that this point is over, it would make the visualization smoother and create "space" for more improvements. By the time I implemented it, I did not find such function.